# nested transformations apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, similarity, euclidean-distance

I need some help about my code, which doesn't response.
I need to compute similarities between items mutually based on their ratings, these similarities will be used to construct the similarity matrix. I have three main functions:

1. the first one help to collect item's ratings
2. the second function compute the similarity between two items
3. the third is dedicated to construct similarity matrix

I have troubles with the third function, since the second perform accurately alone. But when similarity function is called  by the third, the program is blocked and doesn't response without showing any results or either an error.

Comment: First of all, if the first two functions are working fine, please take them out of your question.  Secondly, what profiling have you attempted?  Do you have any thread dumps to share that can help us?

Comment: but the problem resides in the fact that the third one calls the the second.
and the second function contains a transformation, that for what I included the second also.